# How to extract a multi-part rar file on the shell on Ubuntu?

Tags: rar, linux-terminal

I have a very long list of multi-splitted archives like

```
force.part01.rar
force.part02.rar
....
energy.part01.rar
energy.part02.rar
..
dynamic.part1.rar
dynamic.part2.rar
dynamic.part3.rar
....
```

and other 50 multi-splitted archives to extract.

Usually, the command to extract a SINGLE multi-splitted archive is

```
unrar x force.part01.rar
```

but I have too many archives to write all names. Is there a command to extract all `.part01` or `.part1`?

I use terminal on Ubuntu to run commands.

Comment: I've not tried split archives on Linux, but in Windows there's usually the "main file", just named `filename.ext` and a bunch of `filename.partX.ext` files; and just extracting the main file has also extracted the partials. Might be different nowadays, this is over a couple of decades ago... Have you tried using a wildcard, `unrar x force*.rar`?

Comment: yes, but problem is that I have many multi-splitted archives. I can't write manually all 50 names... I need to capture all names `force`, `energy`, `dynamic`, etc without re-write all archives names

Comment: That's what you said, yes. If a folder contains `force.part01.rar`, `force.part02.rar` etc. does it also contain a file `force.rar`? If it does, what happens if you just give command `unrar -x force.rar`- do the part files get also extracted? Have you tried to run a command with a wildcard, so instead of `unrar -x force.part01.rar` and `unrar -x force.part02.rar` just use one command `unrar -x force.*.rar`? If not, try that. If it fails, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1679910/edit) your question to update it with the results; don't answer in a comment.

Comment: @Peregrino69 if I use `unrar x "force.*.rar"` it extract. But this is valid only for **one** multi-part archive. But I want to extract also energy.rar, dynamic.rar and other 50 multi-parts archives without write the names. Something like `unrar x "*.*.rar"`. I need to replace the names with something

Comment: Multple options with a wildcard, one which you just gave there. Easiest `unrar -x *` will decompress every single rar file in the directory.

Comment: @Peregrino69 `unrar -x *` doesn't work but I test now `unrar x "*.*.rar"` and seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command work for me

```
unrar x "*.*.rar"
```

Comment: Please don't forget to check back in 48 hours to accept your answer.

Comment: Seems the quotes are the secret to working with multipart rars, e.g. for listing contents: `unrar lb *.rar` fails but `unrar lb "*.rar"` works thanks.